# Using wc_get_orders() orderby argument for a custom field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, orders

I have a meta field where there is a time entered e.g. 12:0,0 13:03, 01:00... I would like to orderby this field "billing_eta"

currently, I have the below code which I have added the orderby and order args to, however, they are ignored.

how can I order by the time in a meta field?

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'billing_eta', //has no effect as its a meta field 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'status'       => 'completed', // Accepts a string: one of 'pending', 'processing', 'on-hold', 'completed', 'refunded, 'failed', 'cancelled', or a custom order status.
    'meta_key'     => 'billing_date', // Postmeta key field
    'meta_value'   => $ppr_arrival_date, // Postmeta value field
    'meta_compare' => '==', // Possible values are ‘==’, ‘!=’, ‘>’, ‘>=’, ‘<‘, ‘<=’, ‘LIKE’, ‘NOT LIKE’, ‘IN’, ‘NOT IN’, ‘BETWEEN’, ‘NOT BETWEEN’, ‘EXISTS’ (only in WP >= 3.5), and ‘NOT EXISTS’ (also only in WP >= 3.5). Values ‘REGEXP’, ‘NOT REGEXP’ and ‘RLIKE’ were added in WordPress 3.7. Default value is ‘=’.
);

$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
```

it is now work using the following if it helps anyone else:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'completed',
    'orderby' => 'eta',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'arrival_date' => array(
            'key' => 'billing_date',
            'value' => $ppr_arrival_date,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        'eta' => array(
            'key' => 'billing_eta',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'TIME'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the meta key `billing_date` doesn't start with an underscore like `_billing_date` (check it on `wp_postmeta` database table).

Comment: I have tried it with both. I found that on the billing_date both with and without work but with only picked up orders where it was the original value and not ones changed in the Admin panel. I, therefore, assumed it would be the same for the time (billing_eta).

Comment: Yes it should be the same for all custom fields…

Comment: odd that it is different... but either way I still cannot orderby _billing_eta or billing_eta. any ideas?

Comment: Yes it works just like in a [WP_Query for custom fields parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) and orderby parameters.

Answer (score 3):

needed both meta elements in the meta_query thus:

```
$args = array(
    'status' => 'completed',
    'orderby' => 'eta',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'arrival_date' => array(
            'key' => 'billing_date',
            'value' => $ppr_arrival_date,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        'eta' => array(
            'key' => 'billing_eta',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type' => 'TIME'
        ),
    )
);
```